Gannt chart - Multiple task bar in one row
I am using excel to create Gantt chart. I was wondering it is possible to have multiple sub-tasks bar (as in green and yellow - should be in the same row as green) on a single row?  My problem is a sub-task is performed according to the number in column B and C (see picture below), I have used red boxes to show how I would like the bar to appear.  But I am unsure how to structure my data so that it works. I have tried the formula below if i pull it down then it does not work.
=(IF(AND(AB$3>=$B4,AB$3<=$C4),$A4,0))

I tried using the formula if( and() ) to return the value in column A and draw a chart as per attached image.

Why do you want multiple bars to appear on the same line? The answer to this question will help determine what the best solution is.

@FlexYourData, because i want to use the file to monitor gaps between the sections as they are produced weekly. solid line means everything is completed. open space means there is a section pending.

You need to change the references, right now just as example, when you are in row 4 your formula references same row =(IF(AND(AB$3>=$B4,AB$3<=$C4),$A4,0))  and that's the normal behaviour in Excel. In this case, adjust your formula so it references 1 row below.  so it goes something like =(IF(AND(AB$3>=$B5,AB$3<=$C5),$A5,0)) and =(IF(AND(AB$3>=$B6,AB$3<=$C6),$A6,0)) and so on, but this formula goes on cells only of row 4. Anyways, a Gantt chart is not meant to be used as you wish and if you want to monitor gaps probably you need a different visual approach and not a Gantt Chart

@ Foxfire and Burns and Burs, thank you very much for your assistant. Kindly any other visual that I can use in this case highly appreciated.
